# How do I override a Java map when converting a JSON to Java Object using GSON?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a JSON string which looks like this:

```
{
 "status": "status",
 "date": "01/10/2019",
 "alerts": {
     "labels": {
         "field1": "value1",
         "field2": "value2",
         "field3": "value3",
         "field100": "value100"
     },
     "otherInfo" : "other stuff"
 },
 "description": "some description"
}
```

My corresponding Java classes look like the following:

```
public class Status {
    private String status;
    private String date;
    private Alerts alerts;
    private String description;
}
```

And

```
public class Alerts {
    private Map<String, String> labels;
    private String otherInfo;

    public Map<String, String> getLabels() {
        return labels();
    }
}
```

I'm parsing the given JSON into Java object using this:

```
Status status = gson.fromJson(statusJSONString, Status.class);
```

This also gives me Alerts object from Status class:

```
Alerts alerts = status.getAlerts();
```

**Here is my problem:**

Let's consider the `labels`:

I want to make keys in the `label` map the case-insensitive. So for example, if the provided key/value pair is `"field1" : "value1"`, or `"Field1" : "value1"` or `"fIeLD1":"value1"`, I want to be able to retrieve them by simply calling `alerts.getLabels.get("field1")`.

Ideally, I want to set the keys to be lowercase when the `labels` map is originally created. I looked into Gson deserialization examples, but I'm not clear exactly how to approach this.

Comment: I ran the code and I am getting `null` for alerts. Is there anything special that you did for extracting the alert class?

Comment: I got it, the variable name should be `label` instead of `labelMap`. I have edited your question.

Comment: Thanks @ReazMurshed

Comment: Can you please check the answer below? Kudos for clear questions with sufficient amount of code to replicate the issue in my local environment. :)

Comment: @BlueChips23, I know you have already accepted answer but take a look on mine. Maybe it will help you somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own `MapTypeAdapterFactory` which creates `Map` always with lowered keys. Our adapter will be based on `com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory`. We can not extend it because it is `final` but our `Map` is very simple so let's copy only important code:

```
class LowercaseMapTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        TypeAdapter<String> stringAdapter = gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(String.class));

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) { }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                JsonToken peek = in.peek();
                if (peek == JsonToken.NULL) {
                    in.nextNull();
                    return null;
                }

                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

                in.beginObject();
                while (in.hasNext()) {
                    JsonReaderInternalAccess.INSTANCE.promoteNameToValue(in);
                    String key = stringAdapter.read(in).toLowerCase();
                    String value = stringAdapter.read(in);
                    String replaced = map.put(key, value);
                    if (replaced != null) {
                        throw new JsonSyntaxException("duplicate key: " + key);
                    }
                }
                in.endObject();

                return (T) map;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now, we need to inform that our `Map` should be deserialised with our adapter:

```
class Alerts {

    @JsonAdapter(value = LowercaseMapTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    private Map<String, String> labels;

    private String otherInfo;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Assume that our `JSON` `payload` looks like below:

```
{
  "status": "status",
  "date": "01/10/2019",
  "alerts": {
    "labels": {
      "Field1": "value1",
      "fIEld2": "value2",
      "fielD3": "value3",
      "FIELD100": "value100"
    },
    "otherInfo": "other stuff"
  },
  "description": "some description"
}
```

Example usage:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapter;
import com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory;
import com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter;
import com.google.gson.internal.JsonReaderInternalAccess;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonToken;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        Status status = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), Status.class);

        System.out.println(status.getAlerts());
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Alerts{labels={field1=value1, field100=value100, field3=value3, field2=value2}, otherInfo='other stuff'}
```

This is really tricky solution and it should be used carefully. Do not use this adapter with much complex `Map`-es. From other side, `OOP` prefers much simple solutions. For example, create `decorator` for a `Map` like below:

```
class Labels {

    private final Map<String, String> map;

    public Labels(Map<String, String> map) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(map);
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
        map.forEach((k, v) -> this.map.put(k.toLowerCase(), v));
    }

    public String getValue(String label) {
        return this.map.get(label.toLowerCase());
    }

    // toString
}
```

Add new method to `Alerts` class:

```
public Map<String, String> toLabels() {
    return new Labels(labels);
}
```

Example usage:

```
status.getAlerts().toLabels()
```

Which gives you a very flexible and secure behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

There isnt really much you can do here. Even if you extended HashMap, the problem is that when the JSON is de-serialized, it doesn't call native methods. What you COULD do is the following, but it is rather cumbersome:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMapCaseInsensitive extends HashMap<String, String> {

    private boolean convertedToLower = false;

    @Override
    public String put(String key, String value) {
        if(!convertedToLower){
            convertToLower();
        }
        return super.put(key.toLowerCase(), value);
    }

    @Override
    public String get(Object key) {
        if(!convertedToLower){
            convertToLower();
        }
        return super.get(key.toString().toLowerCase());
    }

    private void convertToLower(){
        for(String key : this.keySet()){
            String data = this.get(key);
            this.remove(key);
            this.put(key.toLowerCase(), data);
        }
        convertedToLower = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Generally this is a bad practice to extend internal collection implementations. Better is creating decorator. Also is much better to invoke `convertToLower` method once in constructor.

Comment: @MichałZiober The problem is that the constructor doesnt get called in this situation, because of deserialization. But I agree.

Comment: I know this is a really specific situation but anyway we should try to avoid situations likes that. Moreover it works. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not a very generic solution, however, I think this will serve your purpose.

I would like to suggest you create an adapter for Gson which can convert the map values for you. The adapter might look like the following.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

final class GSONAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<String> {

    private static final GSONAdapter instance = new GSONAdapter();

    static GSONAdapter instance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,
                              JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {

        // Here I am taking the elements which are starting with field
        // and then returning the lowercase version
        // so that the labels map is created this way
        if (jsonElement.getAsString().toLowerCase().startsWith("field"))
            return jsonElement.getAsString().toLowerCase();
        else return jsonElement.getAsString();
    }
}
```

Now just add the `GsonBuilder` to your Gson using the adapter and then try to parse the JSON. You should get all the values in the lower case as you wanted for the `labels`.

Please note that I am just taking the `field` variables in my concern and hence this is not a generic solution which will work for every key. However, if your keys have any specific format, this can be easily applied.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(String.class, GSONAdapter.instance())
        .create();

Status status = gson.fromJson(statusJSONString, Status.class);
Alerts alerts = status.getAlerts();
```

Hope that solves your problem.