# Convert nested JSON Keys to UPPERCASE

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to convert all keys of JSON string/object to UPPERCASE in Java. The JSON can be nested.

I tried setting FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE in GsonBuilder but I guess that just works for String to JAVA Object and not for String to String.

```
 String payload = "{\"key\" : {\"key1\" : \"value1\",\"key2\" : \"value2\"}}";
 GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
 gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(myCustomTypeAdapterFactory);
 gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE);
 Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
 Map mapDeserialized = gson.fromJson(payload, Map.class);

 System.out.println("Map " + mapDeserialized);
```

There are other solutions through JACKSON with custom TypeAdapterFactory but those only work for one level and not for nested.

`{"key" : {
"key1" : "value1",
"key2" : "value2"
}}`

to

`{"KEY" : {
"KEY1" : "value1",
"KEY2" : "value2"
}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override a Java map when converting a JSON to Java Object using GSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912746/how-do-i-override-a-java-map-when-converting-a-json-to-java-object-using-gson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said FieldNamingPolicy is applied only for bean fields not for map keys. However UPPER_CAMEL_CASE is not what you want, it is camel case with first letter capitalized (SometingLikeThis). You have to implement your own deserializer that would do that for your:

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class UpperCaseAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Map<String, Object>>, JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Object>> {
    public static final Type TYPE = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Map<String, Object> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        // TODO implement serialization if needed
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
            Object value = null;
            if (entry.getValue().isJsonPrimitive()) {
                value = entry.getValue().getAsString();
            } else if (entry.getValue().isJsonObject()) {
                value = context.deserialize(entry.getValue(), TYPE); // deserialize the object using the same type
            } else if (entry.getValue().isJsonArray()) {
                // TODO implement deserailization of array
            } else if (entry.getValue().isJsonNull()) {
                // skip nulls
                continue;
            }
            map.put(entry.getKey().toUpperCase(), value); //toUpperCase() is what we want
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

you can use the adapter then:

```
        String payload = "{\"key\" : {\"key1\" : \"value1\",\"key2\" : \"value2\"}, \"key3\": \"value\"}";
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(UpperCaseAdapter.TYPE, new UpperCaseAdapter())
                .create();
        Map<String, Object> mapDeserialized = gson.fromJson(payload, UpperCaseAdapter.TYPE);

        System.out.println("Map " + mapDeserialized);
```

and the output is:
`Map {KEY3=value, KEY={KEY2=value2, KEY1=value1}}`

Comment: Will this solutions work for any level of nested JSON?

Comment: Sure, you can try. There's a recursion that cares about any nested lvl. But if you expect to be an array in the json you have to improve the implementation.

Comment: Thank yooouuu so much. I called the context again for each element of arrya and it worked for 4 levels.

Comment: You're welcome. Just one thing - make sure, the the element of array is json object, if the element is primitive or another array then the call of context.deserialze won't work for the TYPE. The safest way for array deserialization is to implement another adapter, that would expect the json element to be json array and would go through the elements and if the element is object, then call deserialize for map TYPE, if element is array then call desrialize for array type and if element is primitive, then add element as string to the array.